# Not Getting Correct Data Context In Change Event Handler Within Nested Context

Tags: knockout.js

I have a `select` inside of a `with` binding context.

```html
<div data-bind="with: SelectedItem">
    <select id="select" data-bind="options: $root.OptionsList, optionsText: 'description', optionsValue: 'opt_id', event: { change: $parent.OptionSelectionChanged }, optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
</div>
```

The following I would have thought would have output consisting of the selected item in `$root.OptionsList` but instead I'm getting `$root.SelectedItem`.

```js
function MyViewModel() {
    self.OptionSelectionChanged = function(data, event) {
        console.log(data) // outputs $root.SelectedItem
    }
}
```

In this example, `$root.OptionsList` is a list of properties which can be applied to `$root.SelectedItem` (which is a clone of an item in `$root.AvailableItems` which is a list of larger, relational, objects).

So, when the user selects an option from the Select containing `$root.OptionsList` in the change event I update `$root.SelectedItem.SelectedOptions` which causes the UI to update and reset the Select to empty to display the caption again.

How can I get the value of the selected option in a change event? Am I doing something wrong, or are my expectations incorrect/misguided? I have managed to get the value using jQuery and `event.CurrentTarget` but that seems kinda "wrong" even though it works as Knockout, I think, should be sending me the value selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across a scenario to use a `select` binding within a `with` binding without the options being in someway related to the object in the with binding. Also it seems strange on how the `with` binding is changing the `binding context` while sending the element to the `change` handler.

However, a workaround could be to define an `observable` on the `root` object to hold the selected value from the `dropdown` and use the `value` binding in the `select` control

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedItem">
  <select id="select" data-bind="options: $root.OptionsList, optionsText: 'description', optionsValue: 'opt_id', optionsCaption: 'Select', value: $root.selectedOption"></select>
</div>
```

Take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5z6bsc7/1/)

Comment: I think this would work and be more 'knockout friendly' avoiding jQuery, and I expect I am doing Knockout 'wrong' but haven't much experience with this library. I did update my answer to hopefully provide some clarity and context as to what I am doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

- The first parameter to the [`event`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function) bidning is the current [`$data`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) binding context. In your case, it's `SelectedItem`
- If you want to call function on change of the dropdown, use [`subscribe`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables)
- You need to add a `value` binding to the `select`

I still am not sure why you want to add select inside `with:SelectedItem`. If you select the default `select` value in the dropdown, then dropdown won't be visible at all

Here's a working snippet with default `SelectedItem` set on load

```js
function MyViewModel() {
    const self = this;
    self.SelectedItem = ko.observable(1);
    self.OptionsList = ko.observableArray([{description: "1", opt_id:1},{description: "2", opt_id:2}])
    self.SelectedItem.subscribe(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: SelectedItem">
    <select id="select" data-bind="options: $root.OptionsList, optionsText: 'description', optionsValue: 'opt_id', value: $root.SelectedItem, optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: In the real world, OptionsList is a list of properties that can be applied to SelectedItem.SomeProperties and is a static list that's populated on page load and available to any item which becomes the SelectedItem. I'll update my question.